# Flutter Does FutureBuilder reload data after changing page?

Tags: flutter

Use case:

1. FutureBuilder loads data and builds widget*
2. I press a button → I change page/screen
3. I go back to the futureBuilder's screen by pressing a button

Question: Does the futureBuilder reload data ?

Comment: It is unclear how you are changing pages, Can you include [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I'm changing page thanks to Navigator.push

Answer (score 3):

##### It depends

If the future is created at the same time as the `FutureBuilder`, then every time the FutureBuilder's parent is rebuilt, the asynchronous task will be restarted.

*See the [official docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)*

---

In other words if you create the Future directly inside the `future` param,

```dart
  FutureBuilder(
     future: Future.delayed(...), 
     builder: ...
  );
```

then the task is executed on every parent re-render (cause you are actually creating a new Future every time the build method is executed).

You need to create your Future before (like `initState` function), and storing it in some prop, than pass it to the FutureBuilder.

*Something like*

```dart
late Future _myFuture;

initState() {
   super.initState();
   _myFuture = Future.delayed(...);
}

build(context) {
  return FutureBuilder(
     future: _myFuture, 
     builder: ...
  )
}
```

so that in every render, the promise will be the same (and eventually already resolved for future renders)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're pushing another route onto the `Navigator` and then popping it off again? In that case, the underlying screen will not rebuild.

You could `await` the result of the second screen and then reload the data again.

```
// where the second screen is initiated

await Navigator.of(context).push(routeToSecondScreen);
setState(() {});

// in its build method

FutureBuilder(
  future: getData(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    //...
  },
),
```

This will execute a rebuild of the first screen after the second is popped. The rebuild will recreate the `FutureBuilder` and execute the `getData()` function.

However, if the `Future` is part of your screen's state, you might want to execute `myFuture = getData();` within the `setState` function.

```
late Future myFuture;

void initState() {
  super.initState();
  myFuture = getData();
}

// where the second screen is initiated

await Navigator.of(context).push(routeToSecondScreen);
setState(() {
  myFuture = getData();
});

// in its build method

FutureBuilder(
  future: myFuture,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    //...
  },
),
```

Comment: Your initState is backwards.  the super call should always be first.